# mapping and de novo assembly of plant without reference genome

Tags: mapping, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

Hi I'm studying on a plant that has no reference genome and only has one scaffold assembly and one gff3 annotation file. Can I create an index with the same assembly and gff3 in STAR and do the mapping? If I want to do de novo assembly using the Galaxy Can I import the links of 20 fastq files from the RNA-seq of the samples together to construct the Reference Genome with Trinity? If this is possible, please help me import the links of these files together into Galaxy and make the reference genome.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This looks like a question for https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/.  On Stack Overflow, the [tag:assembly] tag is for questions about assembly language / machine code that CPUs execute, not assembly of genetic sequences.  Also, the [tag:galaxy] tag is about Samsung Galaxy phones.  I don't know enough about bioinformatics to tell if there's enough detail for this question to be answerable by people who are familiar with the things you're talking about, but it looks pretty light on details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about using bioinformatics tools, not programming per-se.